# Get all images out of the posts content

Tags: posts, images

I try to get all images out of the content-area of a post. I already tried this

```
$imgs = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $thread->ID
));
```

But this only returns the featured image / the post thumbnail.

I also have tried

```
$imgs = get_post_galleries_images($thread->ID);
foreach($imgs as $img){
    echo $img;
}
```

But this returns nothing.

Any idea how I can get the images out of the content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($post->post_content);
$images = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great :) First time I heard about this functionality! After your code, I looped through the array and got access to the src-attribut via $img->getAttribute("src")

Comment: WordPress just saves the attachment images in the database and not the images inside the content? Is there any method/function to get the image like `wp_get_attachment_image` in order not to working with the DOMs?